# How to make models automatically from database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am following database first approach. Please help me out how can I make models out of my database.

Comment: What kind of models?  What framework?

Comment: database models.. In .net framework

Comment: @Ravindrabagale: No, db context class

Comment: use SQL Server 2005's Visual Data Modeling tools http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1066/sql-server-2005-data-modeling-tools/

Comment: for db context refer this page-http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In sql server management studio, you can expand the database node under [server] => Databases => [database_name], and the first item should be "database diagrams". Right click, hit New Diagram, and you'll be taken to a dialog where you can import the tables you want into the diagram.

The other option is, if you're using a third party data modeling tool, go to [database_name] => Tasks => Generate Scripts, and generate a db creation script. The tools I've used, ERWin and ER Studio, can import those scripts as a model.

Comment: Nevermind, from the comments, it looks like you're not looking for an ER model. In that case, this would be spectacularly unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

ErWin is a common tool, almost an industry standard. You do not HAVE to learn it but it's a nice to know.

Their community edition is free and good to learn about data modeling, both from physical to logical (what you are trying to do here, I guess) and the other way around.

http://erwin.com/downloads/

I would recommend the crow's foot notation, which is now seemingly the industry standard (better than the infinity-key notation which SSMS offers). Hate to link to Wikipedia but this below article is A-OK:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_diagram#Crow.27s_Foot_Notation